# Running second android emulator with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I'm trying to start two emulators simultaneously, for simulating messages between the 5554 and 5556 port. The first emulator runs fine, loads up within a couple minutes. Second one opens, but sticks at the reflecting "a n d r o i d" screen without end. Any ideas on why or how to fix it? I know I've had two emulators running on this computer before, from summer 2012 to early 2013, but because I didn't need to use two anymore, I haven't tried again until now.

I'm on windows, using eclipse to start the emulators. All help appreciated.

Comment: i think your machine is probably slow...run on lower level apis....say run two emulators with gingerbread

Comment: do you know how to send sms from one emulator to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be many reasons behind the slow loading of the emulator:

- Slow or old Laptop/Computer.
- Using latest android ROM images
- Incorrect settings

you can check this post [slow emulator problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow#).

I recommend the following:

1. [Use intel based android images with HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13856866/3193867).
2. Run emulators **without boot animation** using **command line parameters**. To do this take the following steps:

   - first add **android-sdk-path/tools** and android-sdk-path/platform-tools to your **PATH** environment variables. *(This is not required but can be very handy in future)*
   - open **command prompt**.
   - type command `emulator @your-avd-name -no-boot-anim -cpu-delay 0`
3. set emulator affinity to maximum:

   - open **Task manager** when emulator(s) is running.
   - Goto **Processes** tab.
   - <kbd>Right-click</kbd> on **emulator-arm.exe** `>` **Set Affinity...** `>` select all processors
     [image: increase affinity]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to send sms to the emulator you can use the following:

- get on emulator up and running.
- Open `DDMS` perspective
  - Click **Window** menu in the Menubar of Eclipse.
  - select **Open Persperctive** `>` **DDMS**

[image: Opening DDMS in eclipse]

- open tab **Emulator Control**
- Under the **Telephony Actions** select **SMS**
  [image: Using emulator control]
  Now you can insert a number and send SMS to the Emulator.

**NOTE:** You must insert a number before performing any Call/SMS otherwise the controlls will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can change android project run configuration, target as manual selection instead of auto and to to that you have to go to the android project, right click> run as> run configuration and on run configuration window select the project under Android application (right panel) Then select Target tab at left panel, and select manual option. Now whenever you run a project a list with running emulators will apear and if you want to run more than one emulator> open AVD manager > select emulator > click on start > launch

Comment: No I know how to run a second emulator, it's just that the second one is in the loading phase forever, while the first one loads fully.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, and the answer I selected most closely answers the problem of 2 emulators running slowly.

What it turned out to be was that I was using 767MB on an Intel HAXM emulator, and creating 2 of those went over the allocated amount for HAXM. After running 1 Intel and 1 ARM emulator, it worked. The error message was somewhat inconspicuous so I didn't notice it at first.